# AFNetworking doesn't build with cocoapods on xcode8

Tags: ios, cocoapods, afnetworking

I'm on cocoapods 1.1.1, and trying to install this file with `pod install`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
target "Pictabite" do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
    pod 'LLSimpleCamera', '~> 5.0'
end
```

However the project doesn't build after I add AFNetworking. I'm getting this error on Xcode:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFNetworkReachabilityManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in UIDevice+Category.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PBHttpSessionManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PBHttpSessionManager in PBHttpSessionManager.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PBHttpFQSessionManager in PBHttpFQSessionManager.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PBHttpSessionManager in PBHttpSessionManager.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PBHttpFQSessionManager in PBHttpFQSessionManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONResponseSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PBHttpSessionManager.o
      objc-class-ref in PBHttpFQSessionManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PBHttpSessionManager.o
      objc-class-ref in PBHttpFQSessionManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFSecurityPolicy", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PBHttpSessionManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-real: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specifying cocoapods versions, and using `use_frameworks!` yields:

> Installing AFNetworking (3.0.4)
>   Installing LLSimpleCamera (4.2.0)
>   Installing SDWebImage (3.7.5)

- `pod --version`: 1.1.1
- `xcodebuild -version`: Xcode 8.2.1, Build version 8C1002

Your Podfile could look like this:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Pictabite' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'SDWebImage'
    pod 'LLSimpleCamera'
end
```

---

#### Swift 3 Compilation example

```
import AFNetworking
...
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let manager = AFURLSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: configuration)
```

#### Objective-C Compilation example

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
...
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration =
   [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager =
   [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm writing obj-c, not swift. No change in the pod file I'm guessing?

Comment: No `Podfile` difference.